# Sending a double via serial communication from arduino to vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, arduino, usb

I'm trying to make an application in vb.net which can read the temperature from an arduino over a serial communication (USB).

I want that it is possible to only read the temperature when a user clicks on a button.

I have posted my code below. When I click on the button 'BtnManueel_Click' I first send a command to the arduino. When the arduino receives this command, it will read the temperature end send it to the PC. This works perfectly when I use a serial monitor. But when I run my application with the code below, I don't get the value in vb.net.

What am I doing wrong and/or why isn't it working?

I don't have much experience with vb.net and serial communication and I was hoping you could help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

kind regards.

vb.net code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Dim serielepoort As New SerialPort
    Dim celsius As Double

    Private Sub BtnVerbinden_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnVerbinden.Click
        Try
            serielepoort.PortName = "COM8"
            serielepoort.BaudRate = 9600
            serielepoort.DataBits = 8
            serielepoort.Parity = Parity.None
            serielepoort.StopBits = StopBits.One
            serielepoort.Handshake = Handshake.None
            serielepoort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
            serielepoort.ReadTimeout = 10000
            serielepoort.Open()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "fout bij verbinden!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End Try
    End Sub


    Private Sub BtnVerbindingVerbreken_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnVerbindingVerbreken.Click

        serielepoort.Close()

    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

        BtnVerbindingVerbreken_Click(sender, e)

    End Sub


    Private Sub BtnManueel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnManueel.Click

        If (serielepoort.IsOpen) Then
            serielepoort.Write("t")            
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub serialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

        celsius = serielepoort.ReadLine()
        LblTempWaarde.Text = celsius

    End Sub

End Class
```

Code in arduino:

```
nt pinLM335 = 0;


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() >0)
  {
   String val = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
   if (val == "t")
   { int waarde = analogRead(pinLM335);
   double spanning =(waarde / 1024.0)*5;
   double Kelvin = (spanning) * 1000 / 10;
   double celsius = Kelvin - 273.15;

   Serial.println(celsius);
  }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and see if you get any data when constantly sending? Then add the post.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
Class PortDataReceived
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim mySerialPort As New SerialPort("COM1")

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = True

        AddHandler mySerialPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

        mySerialPort.Open()

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.ReadKey()
        mySerialPort.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub DataReceivedHandler(
                        sender As Object,
                        e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
        Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:")
        Console.Write(indata)
    End Sub
End Class
```